# Wrong values when populating select box from sql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a select box that is populated from a sql table. I'd like to display the value of the selected option onto an input field

With the following code, I can successfully populate the select box. However, when I try to display the value of the option ('price'), the input box displays what's in between the option tags instead.

```
<select name="home_size" id="home_size">
   <option value="" selected>select a home size</option>
   <?php
       $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

       if(! $conn ){
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       $qry = "SELECT 
                     phpap_home_size.id, 
                     phpap_home_size.name, 
                     phpap_home_size.price 
                     FROM phpap_home_size";

       if ($retval = mysqli_query($conn, $qry)) {;

       if(! $retval ){
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){
          echo '<option value"'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["name"].'...............................$'.$row["price"].'</option>';
       }

      mysqli_free_result($retval);
  ?>
</select>

<input name="pay_amt" id="pay_amt" type="text" value"">
```

I'm using jquery just to display the value into an input field

```
$('#home_size').change(function() {
    $('#pay_amt').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing equal sign here, (In the option tab)

```
'<option value"'.$row["price"].'">'
```

change it to this

```
'<option value="'.$row["price"].'">'
```

This line is also not right

```
<option value="" selected>select a home size</option>
```

Change to this

```
<option value="selected" >select a home size</option>
```

and change these lines as well as you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

```
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn))
```

also

```
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

There is also a missing `=` in (`value""`)

```
<input name="pay_amt" id="pay_amt" type="text" value"">
                                                    ^
```

Comment: This `mysql_error()` is another factor. Mixing APIs.

Comment: No, both `mysql_error()` and I also spotted `value""` - Edit: You deleted your comment. OP needs to add error reporting also.